# How to change the color in ' \section{.} '

Tags: sections-paragraphs

```
\documentclass[12]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed,  etoolbox}
  \colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2!60}
\usepackage{thmtools} %

\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{frame}[{}]{%
 \thmt@trytwice{}{%
 \RequirePackage{framed}%
 \RequirePackage{thm-patch}%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}
 \addtotheorempreheadhook[\thmt@envname]{%
 \begin{framed}}%
 \addtotheorempostfoothook[\thmt@envname]{\end{framed}}%
 }%
}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section, frame]{definition}
\declaretheorem[frame, sharenumber=definition]{proposition}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proposition}{\colorlet{framecolor}{DarkSeaGreen4}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{Yellow1!15}}





\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][1cm]{\mathrel{%
   \hbox{\rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]{#1}{.4pt}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\myscriptarrow}[1][1cm]{{%
    \hbox{\rule[\scriptratio\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\scriptratio\dimexpr.4pt\relax}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother







\begin{document}
\section{Arithmérique}
\subsection{12}
le but de ce chapitre

    \begin{definition}
        Soit f:$G \rightarrow G$ une application linéaire alors:\\
    $$\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$$
    \end{definition}

    \begin{proposition}
        Soit $f:G \myarrow[.7cm]G$ une application linéaire alors:\\
    $$\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y$$
    \end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: (a) `12` is not a recognized option of the `article` document class. I assume you meant to write `12pt`. (b) Don't load packages more than once. (c) To cut down on code clutter, do replace `\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}` with `\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something how this? You can compare your code with what I entered to understand the answer. Sorry for the speed with which I write to you.

**Addendum:** Thank you very much for the suggestion of @Mico (see the comment).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed, etoolbox}
\colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2!60}
\usepackage{thmtools} %
\usepackage{titlesec}%%%%%% <---------addendum
\titleformat{\section}%%%%%% <---------addendum
{\color{magenta}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}%%%%%% <---------addendum
{\color{magenta}\thesection}{1.5em}{}%%%%%% <---------addendum
\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{frame}[{}]{%
 \thmt@trytwice{}{%
 \RequirePackage{framed}%
 \RequirePackage{thm-patch}%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}
 \addtotheorempreheadhook[\thmt@envname]{%
 \begin{framed}}%
 \addtotheorempostfoothook[\thmt@envname]{\end{framed}}%
 }%
}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section, frame]{definition}
\declaretheorem[frame, sharenumber=definition]{proposition}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proposition}{\colorlet{framecolor}{DarkSeaGreen4}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{Yellow1!15}}

\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][1cm]{\mathrel{%
   \hbox{\rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]{#1}{.4pt}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\myscriptarrow}[1][1cm]{{%
    \hbox{\rule[\scriptratio\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\scriptratio\dimexpr.4pt\relax}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Arithmérique}
\subsection{12}
le but de ce chapitre

    \begin{definition}
    Soit $f\colon G \rightarrow G$ une application linéaire alors:\\%%%%%% <---------edit
   \[\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y\]
    \end{definition}
   \begin{proposition}
        Soit $f\colon G \myarrow[.7cm]G$ une application linéaire alors:\\%%%%%% <---------edit
    \[\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y\]
    \end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

**Addendum (2)**: There is another possibility: to use the @Bernard's comment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed, etoolbox}
\colorlet{framecolor}{VioletRed4}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{LavenderBlush2!60}
\usepackage{thmtools} %
\usepackage{titlesec}%%%%%% <---------addendum
\titleformat*{\section}{\color{magenta}\Large\bfseries} %%%%%% <---------@Bernard's comment
\makeatletter
\define@key{thmdef}{frame}[{}]{%
 \thmt@trytwice{}{%
 \RequirePackage{framed}%
 \RequirePackage{thm-patch}%
    \def\FrameCommand{\fcolorbox{framecolor}{shadecolor}}
 \addtotheorempreheadhook[\thmt@envname]{%
 \begin{framed}}%
 \addtotheorempostfoothook[\thmt@envname]{\end{framed}}%
 }%
}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section, frame]{definition}
\declaretheorem[frame, sharenumber=definition]{proposition}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proposition}{\colorlet{framecolor}{DarkSeaGreen4}
    \colorlet{shadecolor}{Yellow1!15}}

\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][1cm]{\mathrel{%
   \hbox{\rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]{#1}{.4pt}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\myscriptarrow}[1][1cm]{{%
    \hbox{\rule[\scriptratio\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\scriptratio\dimexpr.4pt\relax}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Arithmérique}
\subsection{12}
le but de ce chapitre

    \begin{definition}
    Soit $f\colon G \rightarrow G$ une application linéaire alors:\\%%%%%% <---------edit
   \[\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y\]
    \end{definition}
   \begin{proposition}
        Soit $f\colon G \myarrow[.7cm]G$ une application linéaire alors:\\%%%%%% <---------edit
    \[\forall x,y\in G,\ f(x)=f(y)\iff x=y\]
    \end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Small suggestion: change `f:$G \rightarrow G$` to `$f\colon G \rightarrow G$`, and `$f:G \myarrow[.7cm]G$` to `$f\colon G \myarrow[.7cm]G$`. Also, the explicit line break directives after `alors:` are not needed. Optional: change `\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm, left=3cm, right=3cm]{geometry}` to `\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}`.

Comment: @Sebastiano, what is the commande that must I use it?

Comment: @mohammed Please see the last edit into code: addendum + edit with the symbols `%%%%% <--------`.

Comment: @Sebastiano: `\titleformat*{\section}{\color{magenta}\Large\bfseries}` does the same job,and is easier to understand  for someone who ùay not know very well the package in use. Do you think that ‘Arithmérique’ denotes D. Trump's way of doing fake arithmetic? ;o)

Comment: @Bernard Ahahahah. Now edit again the code with your suggestion.

Comment: @Sebastiano, The solution was successful